# "This field cannot be null" error in a django 1.5 ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms

I managed to create a ModelForm that basically insert an Alert object in DB linked to an Application on an Environment that will send mail to a Contact (managed with ForeignKey). My form (based on a CreateView class-based form) is composed of 3 fields:

- a CharField for the application
- a ModelChoiceField for the environment
- an EmailField for the contact

The CreateView is mixed-in with some AJAX logic to make the submit thing overall dynamic (i.e. drawing tooltips for errors without reloading the page next to each field instead of having a big error  above the form).

The logic of the ModelForm is to:

1. Check if the application already exists in DB. Otherwise it raises a ValidationError
2. Check if the contact mail address exists in DB. Otherwise it creates it
3. Check if the resulting Alert object to create already exists in DB. If it exists it raises a ValidationError.

Everything works fine so far except when I want to submit my form with a non existing contact mail address, the ModelForm raises an "This field cannot be null" validation error.

I really didn't find what I'm doing wrong since I use get_or_create() method in clean_contact() method of my ModelForm to insert this contact if needed then return the resulting object to update self.cleaned_data dictionary. Worst thing is that when I submit a second time the form without changing any field everything runs smooth (no more validation error)...

When I submit the form with an existing mail address in database everything is working fine at the first form submit.

I'd really appreciate if you guys can help to point out what is wrong in my code and why this error is raised whereas every POSTed data is correct.

However I've a little doubt about the AJAX mixin with my CreateView since maybe it could be that when a mail address is not known, get_or_create() create and returns it but - I can't imagine why - the creation of the Alert object could not yet reference the newly created Contact object. This could explain why a second submit works... I'm sure you guys will get the final word on this :-)

Below different application parts involved in the aforementioned issue. I voluntarily removed some Model fields that are not used for this application as well as LoginRequiredMixin inherited from my CreateView.

Again I'd really appreciate your help on that and thank you in advance for every piece of advice.

## Models

```py
class UmsAlerting(models.Model):
    alert_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    appli = models.ForeignKey('UmsApplication')
    env = models.ForeignKey('UmsEnvironment')
    contact = models.ForeignKey('UmsContacts')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ums_alerting'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Alert_Id %d on %s(%s)' %(self.alert_id, self.appli.trigram_ums, self.env.env_name)


class UmsApplication(models.Model):
    appli_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    trigram_ums = models.CharField(max_length=4L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ums_application'


class UmsContacts(models.Model):
    contact_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    mail_addr = models.CharField(max_length=100L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ums_contacts'


class UmsEnvironment(models.Model):
    env_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    env_name = models.CharField(max_length=5L)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ums_environment'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.env_name
```

## ModelForm

```py
class AlertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UmsAlerting
        exclude = ('custom_rule')

    appli = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=3)
    env = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True,
                                 queryset=UmsEnvironment.objects.all())
    contact = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    def clean_appli(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['appli']

        try:
            UmsApplication.objects.get(trigram_ums=data)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            msg = 'Trigram must be known and valid.'
            self._errors['appli'] = self.error_class([msg])
            raise forms.ValidationError(msg)

        return UmsApplication.objects.get(trigram_ums=data)

    def clean_contact(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['contact']
        c, created = UmsContacts.objects.get_or_create(mail_addr=data)

        return c


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AlertForm, self).clean()
        app = cleaned_data.get('appli')
        contact = cleaned_data.get('contact')
        env = cleaned_data.get('env')

        # Do not insert a new alert if it already exists
        if UmsAlerting.objects.filter(appli=app, env=env, contact=contact).count() > 0:
            msg = 'Alert is already configured.'
            self._errors['contact'] = self.error_class([msg])
            raise forms.ValidationError(msg)

        # Return the parent's clean method finally
        return cleaned_data
```

## CreateView

```py
class AlertView(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxResponseMixin, CreateView):
     template_name = 'tools/alert_form.html'
     form_class = AlertForm
     success_url = reverse_lazy('alerts_configure')
```

## AjaxResponseMixin

```py
class AjaxResponseMixin(object):
     def render_to_json_response(self, context, **kwargs):
         data = json.dumps(context)
         kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
         return HttpResponse(data, **kwargs)

     def form_invalid(self, form):
         response = super(AjaxResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
         if self.request.is_ajax():
             return self.render_to_json_response(form.errors, status=400)
         else:
             return response

     # Not really useful actually (yet)
     def form_valid(self, form):
         response = super(AjaxResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)
         if self.request.is_ajax():
             return self.render_to_json_response(json.dumps({}))
         else:
             return response
```

Comment: If you add some tracebacks, it will be easier to tell what goes wrong

Comment: Thanks for your comment alko. Unfortunately there is no traceback. Only a HttpResponse with status code 400 raised by form_invalid method. I tried to add several breakpoints at different places with no chance to find out something. I also tried to dump the cleaned_data that is correct and contains every model object when status 400 is raised.

Comment: but where `This field cannot be null` exception is coming from? and http 400 may be a different issue, coming SuspitiousOperation, for example csrf protection; have you added csrf_token to ajax request?

Comment: `This field cannot be null` is not an exception. It is included in form.errors for the contact field key that is returned in JSON by form_invalid method that I get inside fail() method in my $.ajax query on the client side. By the way I did not add csrf_token to the Ajax request. I will do but I'm not sure if it's the root cause.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of your models and forms in your question? I ask because the Meta class on the AlertForm is excluding custom_rule which isn't on the Alert model.

Comment: Models are up to date. I voluntarily did not add some stuff that is not involved in my problem and to add clarity to this post. custom_rule is a field I'll include later for a new feature. It is also the only thing I removed on the models' code of this post.

Comment: I also tried to make the ajax request to be synchronous and the same problem is observed (i.e. adding an alert with a mail address which is not in DB will insert the contact in the DB but then return "this field cannot be null" in form.errors). The problem seems to be that the contact newly inserted in DB is not usable when the Alert object has to be created in DB after form submission...

Comment: I tried to replace `UmsContacts.objects.get_or_create(mail_addr=data)` with `UmsContacts.objects.get('test_form_1@test.com')` in `clean_contact` to force an existing Contact object to be retrieved instead of creating a new one. **It works without any form errors after the submission**. This basically means that, as guessed, the `get_or_create` method does not allow me to use a newly created Contact object to create an Alert object. But I can't find out why... Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961021/django-get-or-create-does-not-return-a-usable-model-object-in-clean-method-of-mo)

In a nutshell the `UmsContacts` model is using an `IntegerField` so it has to be specified to create a new object like this one even if the auto-increment is set on the database table. The solution was to change it to `AutoField` as well as to return modified `self.cleaned_data['contact']` in `clean_contact` method.