# Django get_or_create does not return a usable Model object in clean method of ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms

Hello,

I have bound a ModelForm to one of my model that contains a ForeignKey to another model everything driven by a CreateView. What I want to achieve is to create the model object corresponding to the foreign key if it doesn't exist before the form is overall validated and the final object created in database.

Below the models I use:

```py
class UmsAlerting(models.Model):
     alert_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
     appli = models.ForeignKey('UmsApplication')
     env = models.ForeignKey('UmsEnvironment')
     contact = models.ForeignKey('UmsContacts')
     custom_rule = models.ForeignKey('UmsCustomRules', null=True, blank=True)

class UmsApplication(models.Model):
     appli_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     trigram_ums = models.CharField(max_length=4L)

class UmsContacts(models.Model):
     contact_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     mail_addr = models.CharField(max_length=100L)

class UmsEnvironment(models.Model):
     env_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     env_name = models.CharField(max_length=5L)
```

The model bound to the form is `UmsAlerting`. The model object I want to create if it doesn't exist is `UmsContacts`. I managed to use the field's `clean` method in my `ModelForm` of the contact field and use the get_or_create method like below:

```py
def clean_contact(self):
     data = self.cleaned_data['contact']
     c, _ = UmsContacts.objects.get_or_create(mail_addr=data)
     return c
```

It perfectly works when the contact is already in the database but when it needs to be created my form return a `ValidationError` on the contact field saying "This field cannot be null". If I submit the same form a second time without changing anything the `UmsAlerting` object is well created with no validation error.

My guess is that, for a reason I don't get, when `get_or_create` is used to create a `UmsContacts` object it cannot be used to create the new `UmsAlerting` object. So in `clean_contact` method the get is working and returns the `UmsContacts` object but the create part doesn't. It'd be like the `UmsContacts` object is saved when the whole form is validated but not before as I'd want it to.

Anyone could help me find out what is the problem ? Is using the clean method not the best idea ? Is there another strategy to use to take around this problem ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please dont create objects in the clean method. See if you can create it in the view, and assign the field to the form there

Comment: Hi karthikr. Thanks for your comment. Should I for example override the `post` method in my `CreateView` ? Btw I do not need to change the field's content since I set it to be an `EmailField`. Sorry I'm a new Django user so I'm not yet familiar with this framework :)

Comment: Yes.. that would be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the object you are creating expects value for contact_id. If you use contact_id field for just setting object id -then you do not have to create it at all. Django takes care of Id's automatically.

Also. field clean method should return cleaned data not object. That creates whole lot more problems on its own.

Comment: Hi Odif. Thanks for your reply. The thing here is that when I first submit the form I get the ValidationError but the new contact is well inserted in the database. The object I return in `clean_contact` is not valid from the `ModelForm` point of view though whereas it is well inserted in database...

Comment: You're absolutely right ! My comment above is dumb. I changed the `contact_id` field in my model to be an `AutoField` as well as change the `self.cleaned_data['contact']` to the get_or_created object and return `self.cleaned_data['contact']`. Everything now runs smooth. Thanks a lot !